# Ordinal superscript in ggplot annotate R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm hoping I can get some help with placing a text label on a ggplot graph (using `annotate`) where the text contains an ordinal suffix as superscript (or whatever the proper term is for that) and a computed value. Despite reading a few questions on SO and SE, I'm having trouble getting this to work.

Here is a minimal example.

```
  # my two attempts at creating the label
  my.var = 10 / 3 # just a toy example
  my.label.expr = paste(expression("20^th*"), " decile ",  round(my.var, 4), sep = "") 
  my.label.bquote = bquote('Lift (' ~  20^th* ~ "decile) : " ~ .  
 (round(my.var, 4), sep = ""))
  test = data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)
  ggplot(aes(x = x , y= y ), data = test) + geom_point() + 
  annotate("text", label = my.label.bquote,parse = TRUE, x = 5, y = 5,    
  colour = "red", size = 7)
```

Using `label = my.label.expr` gives error:

```
# Error in parse(text = lab) : <text>:1:15: unexpected numeric constant
# 1: 20^th* decile 3.3333
```

Using `label = my.label.bquote` causes interpreter to have prompt with a ?

I also tried with `parse = FALSE`, the `my.label.expr` prints, but just displays the text literally, no superscript. With `parse = FALSE` for the bquote solution, it prints nothing at all.

I feel like I've gotten confused between the syntax for each of these options. Is it possible to display a purely alphabetic superscript? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this

```
my.label.expr = paste("20^{th}*' decile '*", round(my.var, 4))

ggplot(aes(x = x , y= y ), data = test) + geom_point() + 
annotate("text", label = my.label.expr, parse=TRUE,
  x = 5, y = 5, colour = "red", size = 7)
```

Here we build the value as a character string with proper `?plotmath` syntax (grouping the exponent in brackets) and then setting `parse=TRUE` so it is evaluated property.

Answer (score 0):

**There are two newer options that people should be aware of instead of using an expression.**

1. html or markdown style text using `ggtext`. This opens up many other formatting options for the text as well.
2. unicode text to encode the superscript text (works with numbers/letters)

## `ggtext` option:

Use the `geom_richtext` function instead of `annotate`. Make a dataframe with the position and label to pass to ggplot.

```r
library(tidyverse)
require(ggtext)
#> Loading required package: ggtext
# my two attempts at creating the label
my.var = 10 / 3 # just a toy example
test = data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)

df_label <- tibble(x=5, y = 5, label = paste("20<sup>th</sup> decile ", round(my.var, 4)))
ggplot(aes(x = x , y= y ), data = test) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_richtext(data = df_label,
                color = "transparent", # gets rid of box outline
                fill = "transparent",  # gets rid of box fill
                text.color = "red", 
                size = 7,
                aes(x=x, y=y,label = label))
```

[image]

## Unicode text option:

```r
#using unicode text
ggplot(aes(x = x , y= y ), data = test) + 
    geom_point() + 
    annotate("text", 
             label = paste("20\u1d57\u02b0 decile", round(my.var, 4)), 
             x = 5, y = 5, colour = "red", size = 7)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>