# How to manipulate different words and letter format just in geom_label part of ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been trying to present my Regression result directly inside a plot. Even though I have achieved the main task, now I need to beautify my graph. Please look at my current plot. I'd like to have R (subscript 2) instead of R^2, (italicized 'p')-value instead of p-value, and actual minus sign instead of hyphen(-) in values.

I am thinking something can be changed in geom_label() section of my code to achieve this result. But because of my limited knowledge I am not able to achieve this.

```
ggplotRegressionr <- function (fit, title_of_graph, n, m) {

  require(ggplot2)

  ggplot(fit$model, aes_string(x = names(fit$model)[2], y = names(fit$model)[1])) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_line() + 
    geom_label(aes(1990, m, hjust = 0, vjust = 0, 
                   label = paste("R^2 = ",signif(summary(fit)$adj.r.squared, 3),"\n",
                                 "Slope =",signif(fit$coef[[2]], 3),"\n",
                                 "p-value =",signif(summary(fit)$coef[2,4], 3)))) +
    stat_smooth(method = "lm", col = "red") + 
    xlab("Year") + ylab("Total Precipitation") +
    labs(title = title_of_graph) + 
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, n)) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Current graph output:
[image: Current graph output i have achieved is in the image]

Comment: `bquote` will help. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33950219/ordinal-superscript-in-ggplot-annotate-r

Comment: Thank you so much. The link you sent gave some useful insights.

Answer (score 2):

If you're a latex fan, you can use the package `latex2exp`, though I faced a problem, which was that I couldn't add new lines between the values so I used a layer for each value plus a layer for a background white box, it's a bit of work since you have to select the right coordinates for the text and white rectangle, but it does the job, here's what I mean:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(latex2exp)

# Dummy values
r2 <- - 0.00888
sl <- - 0.00777
p <- 0.666

# text for the labels
# with gsub add space after the minus sign to get the right sign when latex is rendered 
txt1 <- paste0("$R^2 = ", gsub('-', '- ', r2), "$")
txt2 <- paste0("$Slope = ", gsub('-', '- ', sl), "$")
txt3 <- paste0("$\\mathit{p}-value = ", gsub('-', '- ', p), "$")

# plot
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  geom_smooth(method = lm)  +
  annotate('rect', 
           xmin = 5, xmax = 6.1,
           ymin = 39, ymax = 45,
           size=0.5, 
           fill = 'white', color = 'black') +
  annotate('text', x=5.1, y=43.5, 
           hjust = 0, vjust = 0, 
           size=5,
           label=TeX(txt1)) + 
      #     label=TeX('$R^2 = - 1.5$'), parse = TRUE) + 
  annotate('text', x=5.1, y=41.5,
           hjust = 0, vjust = 0, 
           size=5,
           label=TeX(txt2)) + 
  annotate('text', x=5.1, y=39.5, 
           hjust = 0, vjust = 0, 
           size=5,
           label=TeX(txt3))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @DS_UNI. That worked really well. Is there any work around for the "minus sign". Because even in the graph you have attached the minus sign shown is actually a hyphen. Is there any way we can add a actual minus sign instead of hyphen. Please let me know if that is possible.

Comment: Yes of course, I didn't notice that the minus sign was not rendered correctly and that is because the space between the sign and number is removed when it is converted to character, and the space is needed to render the minus correctly, I edited the answer to guarantee the existence of the space